# Как задать периодическое выполнение скрипта на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Нужно снимать дамп базы данных и высылать его на почту раз в неделю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобных задач существует специальный демон - cron. Для его настройки используют команду crontab. Например, чтобы раз в минуту писать в файл текстовую фразу достаточно
 1. Открыть редактор настроек `crontab -e`
 2. Добавить запись `*/1 * * * * echo wow >> /home/user/wow.txt`
 3. Сохранить изменения и выйти из редактора.